# openURL seems not to be called when app launching

Tags: ios, openurl

When my app is running on background (not killed), openURL is called (for facebook).
However, openURL seems not to be called when my app is killed.
Do you have any experience about it?

Answer (score 0):

If your app has been killed and needs to be launched to open the URL, the `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` methods are called instead of `openURL`.

This is mentioned in the [docs as well](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:)

Comment: Thanks. it's perfect.